# Корректность употребления оборота "Какое время"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Допустимо ли выражение "Какое время кефир может находиться вне холодильника"?

Корректно ли употреблять "Какое время"?

Answer (score 1):

"Какое время" в вопросе предполагает ответ в цифрах. В формальном контексте это вполне допустимо. Альтернатива "сколько времени" не столь навязчива, менее формальна и допускает самый приблизительный ответ.

Comment: Мне кажется, чаще употребляют фразу "Как долго?"

Comment: "Как долго" имеет _ограниченное_ употребление. Здесь оно может подойти к имеющемуся падежу, но совершенно неупотребимо с предложными сочетаниями. Не случайно в математических задачниках фигурирует "**за** какое время (поезд пройдёт и т. п.)?", "какое время он ехал?". https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=IWyLAQAAQBAJ&hl=ru&pg=PA83&img=1&zoom=3&sig=ACfU3U1Or3YB1to5CUPnsFWTj1n_KgMkBA&w=1280 Таков технический подход, в отличие от бытового или чисто филологического, На "как долго?" можно ответить "до вечера" и даже "до полной усталости".

Answer (score 1):

Хотя употребление словосочетания "какое время" в данном случае не является ошибкой, предпочтительней будет сказать "сколько времени" или "как долго".

"Какое время" скорее может употребляться в смысле "какие времена" (т.е. "какая эпоха"). Например, перу известного московского публициста Ильи Смирнова принадлежит полемическая статья "Какое время на дворе - таков мессия".